# Need ownership of newly created file to automatically switch to me.

Tags: server, permissions, files, plex, automatic

I'm creating a Plex server and adding the files to the server with a share drive.  I add these files from a macbook onto the server computer.  When I add them, the owner of the files becomes "nobody" and locks the file.  Which causes Plex to not be able to fetch the metadata.  I can change the ownership of the files with Sudo chown.  But I have to do it every time I add a file.  Is there a way for the ownership to auto change to me when I add a file?

Comment: How are you copying the files from your Macbook to your Plex server?  What commands are you using?  Maybe something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994784/change-ownership-of-file-during-copy could help?